# Dash Plotly how to fix "All arguments should have the same length. x and y"

Tags: charts, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash, linechart

I am using Dash Plotly to make a chart.
When the x length is equal to y length, Dash displays the chart, but when x and y lengths are not equal, it throughs an error.

here is the error:

```
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 3, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is 368
```

*x value*:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04',
           '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06', '2017-01-07', '2017-01-08',
           '2017-01-09', '2017-01-10',
           ...
           '2017-12-25', '2017-12-26', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28',
           '2017-12-29', '2017-12-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-01',
           '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=368, freq='D')
```

*Y value:*

```
0                                     Violent protests
1    Confrontational protests (illegal and non viol...
7        Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)
```

and graph:

```
graph = px.line(df, x=Date, y=Categories,  color=Categories, markers=True,)
```

I want to make this chart:

[image]

How to fix the issue and make this graph?

**UPDATE 1**

Overall data:

[image]

The logic of how the chart should be generated:

[image]

this image shows how the chart above is generated using excel.

I want to generate the same chart using Dash Plotly.

**UPDATE 2**

all data from CSV file:

```
id  date_x  Agency  Relevance_x Human_Validation    Event   Categories of event start date  end date    Duration    Issue   Local-National  Location_Category   Location_Province   Oganizer_type   CivilSocietySector  MainPoliticalSector CS_Location_Category    CS_Location_Province    size_of_participants    Arena_type  Arena_Province
45803   1/1/2018 7:19   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests    12/29/2017  12/29/2017  1   Economic    National    Town    Khuzestan   Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Khuzestan
45817   1/1/2018 7:46   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Confrontational protests (illegal and non violent)          1   Labour  Local   City    Azerbaijan, East    Workers Labour  Neutral Province Center Azerbaijan, East    medium group <50    Working places  Azerbaijan, East
45531   1/1/2018 18:17  ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    City    Isfahan Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Isfahan
45529   1/1/2018 18:23  ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    Province Center Markazi Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Markazi
45448   1/2/2018 6:36   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    Province Center Kurdistan   Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Kurdistan
45299   1/2/2018 10:05  ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Confrontational protests (illegal and non violent)          1   Economic    National    Capital Tehran  Unknown Student Movement    Neutral Capital Tehran  unknown University campuses Tehran
45029   1/3/2018 6:43   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    Town    Kermanshah  Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Kermanshah
44950   1/3/2018 8:49   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    Province Center Bushehr GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Bushehr unknown Streets Bushehr
44935   1/3/2018 9:22   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    Province Center Khuzestan   GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Khuzestan   unknown Streets Khuzestan
44935   1/3/2018 9:22   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    City    Khuzestan   GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Khuzestan   unknown Streets Khuzestan
44935   1/5/2018 9:22   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    City    Khuzestan   GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Khuzestan   unknown Streets Khuzestan
```

Comment: you are not using **Plotly Express** API as I would expect.  what's the overall structure of your data frame?  `df.head(10)`

Comment: @RobRaymond  I have updated the question and provided the necessary data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- always provide your sample data as text not images
- this is very simple to plot, based on structuring data.  Keeping **date** in index and each column being a line it simplifies to `px.line(dfp, markers=True)`
- the core of your issue is that you are passing inconsistent arrays.  Use the structured data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# fmt: off
L=24*5
events=["Protest"]
cat = ["Violent protests","Confrontational protests (illegal and non violent)","Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent"]
iss = ["Economic","Political","Labour"]
ln = ["Local","National"]

# generate some sample data...
df = pd.DataFrame({"date_x":pd.date_range("1-jan-2018", freq="1H", periods=L), "Event":np.random.choice(events,L),
             "Categories of event":np.random.choice(cat, L), "Issue":np.random.choice(iss,L), "Local-National":np.random.choice(ln, L)})
# fmt: on
df = df.sample(50)  # take random subset of data so total events varies by day
# sumarise data frame for plotting.  NB dates are in the index
dfp = (
    df.groupby([df["date_x"].dt.date, "Categories of event"])
    .size()
    .unstack("Categories of event")
    .assign(Events=lambda d: d.sum(axis=1))
).fillna(0)
# now it's very simple to plot...
px.line(dfp, markers=True).update_layout(
    xaxis={"dtick":"D"},
    legend=dict(
        yanchor="bottom", y=-1, xanchor="center", title_text="", x=.5
    ),
)
```

[image]

#### updated - use provided sample data

- make sure *date_x* is correct data type
- column to drive totals is *Event*

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# fmt: off
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id  date_x  Agency  Relevance_x Human_Validation    Event   Categories of event start date  end date    Duration    Issue   Local-National  Location_Category   Location_Province   Oganizer_type   CivilSocietySector  MainPoliticalSector CS_Location_Category    CS_Location_Province    size_of_participants    Arena_type  Arena_Province
45803   1/1/2018 7:19   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests    12/29/2017  12/29/2017  1   Economic    National    Town    Khuzestan   Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Khuzestan
45817   1/1/2018 7:46   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Confrontational protests (illegal and non violent)          1   Labour  Local   City    Azerbaijan, East    Workers Labour  Neutral Province Center Azerbaijan, East    medium group <50    Working places  Azerbaijan, East
45531   1/1/2018 18:17  ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    City    Isfahan Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Isfahan
45529   1/1/2018 18:23  ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    Province Center Markazi Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Markazi
45448   1/2/2018 6:36   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    Province Center Kurdistan   Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Kurdistan
45299   1/2/2018 10:05  ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Confrontational protests (illegal and non violent)          1   Economic    National    Capital Tehran  Unknown Student Movement    Neutral Capital Tehran  unknown University campuses Tehran
45029   1/3/2018 6:43   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Violent protests            1   Economic    National    Town    Kermanshah  Unknown None    Neutral National    NONE    unknown Streets Kermanshah
44950   1/3/2018 8:49   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    Province Center Bushehr GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Bushehr unknown Streets Bushehr
44935   1/3/2018 9:22   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    Province Center Khuzestan   GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Khuzestan   unknown Streets Khuzestan
44935   1/3/2018 9:22   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    City    Khuzestan   GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Khuzestan   unknown Streets Khuzestan
44935   1/5/2018 9:22   ILNA    Yes 1   Protest Demonstrative protests (legal and nonviolent)           1   Political   National    City    Khuzestan   GONGO   Progovernment   Conservative    National    Khuzestan   unknown Streets Khuzestan"""), 
                 sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
# fmt: on

df["date_x"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_x"])
dfp = (
    df.groupby([df["date_x"].dt.date, "Event"])
    .size()
    .unstack("Event")
    .assign(Events=lambda d: d.sum(axis=1))
).fillna(0)

# now it's very simple to plot...
px.line(dfp, markers=True).update_layout(
    xaxis={"dtick":"D"},
    legend=dict(
        yanchor="bottom", y=-1, xanchor="center", title_text="", x=.5
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you @RobRaymond. could you explain what "L=24*5" is? and also "fmt: off/on"

Comment: fat:on/off,  I use Black formatter https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. I didn't want it to format lines between those comments.  **L** is length of dataframe I simulate.  Generating 5 days with 24 hours in each

Comment: I tried to figure it out. and I made some changes to it, but it doesn't produce the chart in the question with exact values. any idea? or what should I do?

Comment: your data is an image do it's unusable by me (I'm not going g to type it in...). the answer generates a random data set to plot due to this

Comment: Thank you for being patient. I have provided all data from a CSV file.
I got stuck at this and can't figure it out. I do really appreciate your help.

Comment: updated - very simple :-) providing data as an image is a real anti-pattern on SO